# Resizing each image based on dimensions in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, image

I've got a basic concept of how to achieve this result, however i can't seem to actually obtain the results i want. I'm creating fixed containers of 100px (height) x 75px (width) in which images are stored. I'm then attempting to use jQuery to run a check on whether or not the images height is bigger than it's width, visa versa or they are equal. If they are equal or the width is bigger, i set those to 100% each and set height as auto, whereas if the height is the greater value, i set that to 100% and width to auto. Below is the current code I have which is resizing the images, but not to how i would like them too.

**HTML**

```
<div id="imagesContainer">
    <div style="height: 100px; width: 75px; border: 1px solid RGB(0, 0, 0);">
        <div class="thumbImage">
            <img src="INSERT 100 x 500 IMAGE HERE"></img>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="height: 100px; width: 75px; border: 1px solid RGB(0, 0, 0);">
        <div class="thumbImage">
            <img src="INSERT 250 x 280 IMAGE HERE"></img>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="height: 100px; width: 75px; border: 1px solid RGB(0, 0, 0);">
        <div class="thumbImage">
            <img src="INSERT 100 x 100 IMAGE HERE"></img>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="height: 100px; width: 75px; border: 1px solid RGB(0, 0, 0);">
        <div class="thumbImage">
            <img src="INSERT 1800x900 IMAGE HERE"></img>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".thumbImage").children("img").each(function(){
    if ($(this).height() > $(this).width()) {
        $(this).css({
            height: '100%',
            width: 'auto'
        });
    } else if ($(this).height() < $(this).width() || ($(this).height() == $(this).width()) {
        $(this).css({
            height: 'auto',
            width: '100%'
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Does it do anything? Can you set up a jsfiddle for this, so we can see what is happening?

Comment: It is supposed to resize the images so that they fit inside the containers correctly. I wrote this in my description of the problem.

Comment: You should to calculate ratio width/height of image and ratio width/height of container (in this case 0.75) and compare it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are testing on the difference between the picture's height and width... It would work flawlessly if the container was square, but since it is a rectangle, it is wrong.

Here:

```
$(".thumbImage").children("img").each(function(){
    imgRatio = $(this).height()/$(this).width();
    containerRatio = $(this).parent().height()/$(this).parent().width();
    if (imgRatio > containerRatio) {
        $(this).css({
            height: '100%',
            width: 'auto'
        });
    } else {
        $(this).css({
            height: 'auto',
            width: '100%'
        });
    }
});
```

Not sure if the code is 100% correct, did not test. But basically we test on the RATIO of the height/width and compare it with the container's ratio to be able to decide what resize we do.

Comment: I'll look into this and see how it works for me. I am looking for something very similar though as I want it so if i re-size the surrounding container the image simply reacts the same whatever dimensions i decide to make it.

Comment: Cheers. I'll have a play around with it and understand how it works!

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in your script, and '.thumbImage' must be set to a height of 100%:

Syntax error:

```
if( $(this).height() < $(this).width() || ($(this).height() == $(this).width() ) )
```

(You missed a closing bracket)

CSS:

```
.thumbImage {
    height:100%;
}
```

JS Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/fMhr2/1/

Also, you should calculate the ratio to get it to work properly, like Salketer just mentioned. I added that to this JSFiddle

Comment: Nice one! I'll mark Salketer's answer as correct but thank you for providing the fiddle, I was just working on one to demonstrate the issue I had but you've both solved it pretty quickly.